# Width of webpage doesn't match screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, web

So my webpage [appr.co/work/work.html](http://appr.co/work/work.html) doesn't display correctly on mobile devices. What happens is that the min-width appears to be 960px, and on iPhone 5 where I tested it, the screen width is 568px, and it ends up zooming out to make the page fit, but consequentially everything looks too small, and the navbar doesn't revert to its mobile look. 
I've tried

```
$("*").css({"min-width": "568px"});
```

As a test to see if it would display correctly, but it still was 960px but now with white space on the right from getting thinner. please help!

Comment: Welcome on SO! Unfortunately, your "question" does not include any actual question. So what is it we should help you with? It would also help if you would post the minimal required HTML and CSS here.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any JS to make your webpage render correctly in mobile devices. Just use @media for that. Look this info for that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries .

So for 568px you can write

`@media only screen and (max-width:568px){
     .class{property:value;}
}` .

Also don't forget to include `meta` tag to get working media queries on real devices (Just include `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` in `head` tag). More info is here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/ .